# How do I override css for a particular control?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I created a solution, stuck in jquery ui to do some slider bars which work and look great.

I popped an accordion onto a page and the CSS for it is awful. But I have no idea how to replace it with my own CSS, as it seems to use an absolute TON of CSS classes and overriding them all seems very messy.

Presumably picking and choosing styles and themes with JQuery UI is a common task, is there a best practice for this?

I'm thinking perhaps you can get the individual component CSS and pre-compile it or similar. But there seem to be many common CSS styles that are applied by jquery ui.

For example, an accordion has these classes automatically applied:

```
ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active
```

I can see that two contain the word 'accordion' and so you can imagine 'overriding' (or should that be removing the code from the jqueryui css and putting it into my own css class?) them without issue, but the others are buried in jquery ui and overriding them globally would likely cause issues.

My goal is to completely customise the accordion control with my own CSS while not affecting any other jquery ui component.

Comment: 11.7K Questioning without any code?

Comment: Sorry, it's a general question, more about the design of implementing jquery ui as to how you manage CSS when you wish to customise it. I'll update my question.

Comment: Yes, please consider updating your question, also lil friendly explanation of what exactly you are looking for would be helpful as well :)

Comment: Thanks. PS: All my rep is from asking dumb questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-declare the same in your stylesheet at the end of all the other styles and set to your custom values that you want to override. After doing that, re-declare that css file at the end of the page. Hope this helps.

Comment: I would follow this same path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the original style as it is then wrap one div around your accordion and inherit the css as you want. Anytime you can remove that class from div to get the default jquery accordion. like:

```
<div class='someClass'> 
<div class='ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active'></div>
</div>
```

CSS would be like this:

```
.someClass .ui-accordion-content { /* your necessary styles */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both above answers seem to fit your needs, in the interest of completeness though you could also over-ride the css using jQuery simply picking out the elements that you're not happy with, e.g.

```
$(".ui-accordion-content").css("color", "#FFF");
```

Might be simpler than digging it out in the jquery-ui css or re-declaring if you're only looking to change one or two items.